# How do i do a multidimensional array calculation using MPI and gather all values into rank 0?

Tags: c, mpi

I have a code that does some heavy calculations. I'm trying to parallelize this heavy calculation into multiple nodes, also using OpenMP. Then, I want to gather all the values into a single array and write it to a .txt file using only rank 0. I'm taking the snippet of the code. For some reason that I can't figure out, this code is giving me a segfault. I'm also a beginner in parallel computation using MPI and OpenMP, so excuse any beginner's errors.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <mpi.h>

#define PARAMETER_1 32
#define PARAMETER_2 32
#define PARAMETER_3 32
#define PARAMETER_4 32

double heavy_function(double arg1, double arg2, double arg3, double arg4){
    //heavy function calculation ...
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    int rank, size;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    int i, j, k, l;
    int local_start, local_end, local_size;
    int flag;
    double p1_values[PARAMETER_1], p2_values[PARAMETER_2], p3_values[PARAMETER_3], p4_values[PARAMETER_4];

    local_size = PARAMETER_1 / size;
    int remainder = PARAMETER_1 % size;
    local_start = rank * local_size;
    local_end = local_start + local_size;
    if (rank == size - 1) {
        local_end += remainder;
    }

    double ****results_values_local;
    results_values_local = (double ****) malloc(local_size * sizeof(double ***));
    for (j = 0; j < PARAMETER_B ; j++) {
        results_values_local[j] = (double ***) malloc(PARAMETER_2  * sizeof(double **));
        for (k = 0; k < PARAMETER_NE; k++) {
            results_values_local[j][k] = (double **) malloc(PARAMETER_3 * sizeof(double *));
            for (l = 0; l < PARAMETER_TE; l++) {
                results_values_local[j][k][l] = (double *) malloc(PARAMETER_4  * sizeof(double));
            }
        }
    }



    double ****results_values_all;
    results_values_all = (double ****)malloc(PARAMETER_1 * sizeof(double ***));
    for (j = 0; j < PARAMETER_1; j++) {
        results_values_all[j] = (double ***)malloc(PARAMETER_2 * sizeof(double **));
        for (k = 0; k < PARAMETER_2; k++) {
            results_values_all[j][k] = (double **)malloc(PARAMETER_3 * sizeof(double *));
            for (l = 0; l < PARAMETER_3; l++) {
               results_values_all[j][k][l] = (double *)malloc(PARAMETER_4 * sizeof(double));
            }
        }
    }

    if (rank == 0) {
        // Only rank 0 opens and reads the files
        fprintf(stderr,"Number of processes: %d \n", size);
        FILE *file_p1;
        file_p1 = fopen("p1.txt", "r");
        FILE *file_p3;
        file_p3 = fopen("p3.txt", "r");
        FILE *file_p4;
        file_p4 = fopen("p4.txt", "r");
        FILE *file_p2;
        file_p2 = fopen("p2.txt", "r");

        if (file_p1 == NULL || file_p2 == NULL || file_p3 == NULL || file_p4 == NULL) {
            printf("Error Reading File\n");
            MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 1);
        }

        // Read p1_values
        for (i = 0; fscanf(file_p1, "%lf", &p1_values[i]) == 1; i++) {
            // Do nothing inside the loop body, everything is done in the for loop header
        }
        // Read p2_values
        for (i = 0; fscanf(file_p2, "%lf", &p2_values[i]) == 1; i++) {
            // Do nothing inside the loop body, everything is done in the for loop header
        }
        // Read p3_values
        for (i = 0; fscanf(file_p3, "%lf", &p3_values[i]) == 1; i++) {
            // Do nothing inside the loop body, everything is done in the for loop header
        }
        // Read p4_values
        for (i = 0; fscanf(file_p4, "%lf", &p4_values[i]) == 1; i++) {
            // Do nothing inside the loop body, everything is done in the for loop header
        }
        fclose(file_p1);
        fclose(file_p2);
        fclose(file_p3);
        fclose(file_p4);
    }

    // Broadcast parameter values to all ranks
    MPI_Bcast(p1_values, PARAMETER_p1, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Bcast(p2_values, PARAMETER_p2, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Bcast(p3_values, PARAMETER_p3, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Bcast(p4_values, PARAMETER_p4, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if(rank ==0)fprintf(stderr,"Calculating the results. This can take a while...\n");

    omp_set_num_threads(omp_get_num_threads());

    #pragma omp parallel for collapse(4)
    for (i = local_start; i < local_end; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < PARAMETER_p2; j++) {
            for (k = 0; k < PARAMETER_p3; k++) {
                for (l = 0; l < PARAMETER_p4; l++) {
                    results_values_local[i- local_start][j][k][l] = log10(heavy_function(pow(10, p1_values[i]), pow(10, p2_values[k]), pow(10, p3_values[l]), pow(10, p4_values[j])));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);  // Add a barrier synchronization point

    // Gather local values from all processes into results_values_all on rank 0
    int *recvcounts = (int*)malloc(size * sizeof(int));
    int *displs = (int*)malloc(size * sizeof(int));
    int local_size_array[size];

    // Calculate the sizes and displacements for each rank
    for (int r = 0; r < size; r++) {
        local_size_array[r] = PARAMETER_p1 / size;  // Equal division of elements
        if (r == size - 1) {
            local_size_array[r] += remainder;  // Add remainder to the last rank
        }
        recvcounts[r] = local_size_array[r] * PARAMETER_p2 * PARAMETER_p3 * PARAMETER_p4;
        displs[r] = ((r > 0) ? displs[r-1] + recvcounts[r-1] : 0);
    }

if (rank == 0) fprintf(stderr,"Gathering all the values from all the ranks to rank 0.\n");  
MPI_Allgatherv(&(results_values_local[0][0][0][0]), local_size_array[rank] * PARAMETER_p2 * PARAMETER_p3 * PARAMETER_p4, MPI_DOUBLE, &(results_values_all[0][0][0][0]), recvcounts, displs, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if (rank == 0) fprintf(stderr,"Writing down the table...\n");

    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);  // Add a barrier synchronization point

    if(rank ==0){
        FILE *file_result;
        file_result = fopen("result.txt", "w");
        #endif
        fprintf(file_result, "p1, p2, p3, p4, results_value\n");
        // run for logarithm values
        for (i = 0; i < PARAMETER_p1; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < PARAMETER_p2; j++) {
                for (k = 0; k < PARAMETER_p3; k++) {
                    for (l = 0; l < PARAMETER_p4; l++) {
                        fprintf(file_result, "%.2f, %.2f, %.2f, %.2f, %.8e\n", p1_values[i], p2_values[j], p3_values[k], p4_values[l], results_values_all[i][j][k][l]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        fclose(file_result);
    }

    MPI_Finalize();

    for (i = 0; i < PARAMETER_p1; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < PARAMETER_p2; j++) {
            for (k = 0; k < PARAMETER_p3; k++) {
                free(results_values_all[i][j][k]);
            }
            free(results_values_all[i][j]);
        }
        free(results_values_all[i]);
    }
    free(results_values_all);


    for (i = 0; i < PARAMETER_p2; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < PARAMETER_p3; j++) {
            for (k = 0; k < PARAMETER_p4; k++) {
                free(results_values_local[i][j][k]);
            }
            free(results_values_local[i][j]);
        }
        free(results_values_local[i]);
    }
    free(results_values_local);
    printf("Results txt created sucessfully! Exitting...\n");

    return 0;
}
```

I think the main problem lies in the MPI_Allgatherv function. I've tried messing with the parameters, but everything seems alright. I'm running on a cluster and debugging with gdb. This is what is happening:

Logfile from the cluster:

```
Gathering all the values from all the ranks to rank 0[a01n01:2969321] *** Process received signal ***
[a01n01:2969321] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[a01n01:2969321] Signal code:  (3)
[a01n01:2969321] Failing at address: 0x39600000fbe20018
[a01n01:2969321] [ 0] linux-vdso64.so.1(__kernel_sigtramp_rt64+0x0)[0x2000000504d8]
[a01n01:2969321] [ 1] /lib64/libibverbs.so.1(+0x11018)[0x2000035f1018]
[a01n01:2969321] [ 2] /lib64/libibverbs.so.1(+0x129e0)[0x2000035f29e0]
[a01n01:2969321] [ 3] /lib64/libibverbs.so.1(ibv_reg_mr+0x3c)[0x2000035f2d0c]
[a01n01:2969321] [ 4] /spack-envs/base/opt/linux-rhel8-ppc64le/gcc-9.1.0/spectrum-mpi-10.4.0.3-20210112-6jbupg3thjwhsabgevk6xmwhd2bbyxdc/container/../lib/pami_port/libpami.so.3(_ZN4PAMI6Device3IBV12IBVMRManager9create_mrEPvmPN>[a01n01:2969321] [ 5] /spack-envs/base/opt/linux-rhel8-ppc64le/gcc-9.1.0/spectrum-mpi-10.4.0.3-20210112-6jbupg3thjwhsabgevk6xmwhd2bbyxdc/container/../lib/pami_port/libpami.so.3(_ZN4PAMI14MemregionCache15createMemregionEPNS_9Me>[a01n01:2969321] [ 6] /spack-envs/base/opt/linux-rhel8-ppc64le/gcc-9.1.0/spectrum-mpi-10.4.0.3-20210112-6jbupg3thjwhsabgevk6xmwhd2bbyxdc/container/../lib/pami_port/libpami.so.3(_ZN4PAMI7Context21memregion_create_implEPvmPmPA24>[a01n01:2969321] [ 7] /spack-envs/base/opt/linux-rhel8-ppc64le/gcc-9.1.0/spectrum-mpi-10.4.0.3-20210112-6jbupg3thjwhsabgevk6xmwhd2bbyxdc/container/../lib/pami_port/libpami.so.3(PAMI_Memregion_create+0x18)[0x20000342c1f8]
[a01n01:2969321] [ 8] /spack-envs/base/opt/linux-rhel8-ppc64le/gcc-9.1.0/spectrum-mpi-10.4.0.3-20210112-6jbupg3thjwhsabgevk6xmwhd2bbyxdc/container/../lib/pami_port/libpami.so.3(_ZN4PAMI8Protocol4Send9EagerRgetINS_6Device3IBV11>[a01n01:2969321] [ 9] /spack-envs/base/opt/linux-rhel8-ppc64le/gcc-9.1.0/spectrum-mpi-10.4.0.3-20210112-6jbupg3thjwhsabgevk6xmwhd2bbyxdc/container/../lib/pami_port/libpami.so.3(PAMI_Send+0x58)[0x200003424a38]
[a01n01:2969321] [10] /spack-envs/base/opt/linux-rhel8-ppc64le/gcc-9.1.0/spectrum-mpi-10.4.0.3-20210112-6jbupg3thjwhsabgevk6xmwhd2bbyxdc/container/../lib/pami_port/libcollectives.so.3(_ZN7LibColl18NativeInterfaceP2PILb1ELb0EE1>[a01n01:2969321] [11] /spack-envs/base/opt/linux-rhel8-ppc64le/gcc-9.1.0/spectrum-mpi-10.4.0.3-20210112-6jbupg3thjwhsabgevk6xmwhd2bbyxdc/container/../lib/pami_port/libcollectives.so.3(_ZN7LibColl18NativeInterfaceP2PILb1ELb0EE9>[a01n01:2969321] [12] /spack-envs/base/opt/linux-rhel8-ppc64le/gcc-9.1.0/spectrum-mpi-10.4.0.3-20210112-6jbupg3thjwhsabgevk6xmwhd2bbyxdc/container/../lib/pami_port/libcollectives.so.3(_ZN4CCMI8Executor10AllgathervINS_17Connect>[a01n01:2969321] [13] /spack-envs/base/opt/linux-rhel8-ppc64le/gcc-9.1.0/spectrum-mpi-10.4.0.3-20210112-6jbupg3thjwhsabgevk6xmwhd2bbyxdc/container/../lib/pami_port/libcollectives.so.3(_ZN4CCMI8Executor10AllgathervINS_17Connect>[a01n01:2969321] [14] /spack-envs/base/opt/linux-rhel8-ppc64le/gcc-9.1.0/spectrum-mpi-10.4.0.3-20210112-6jbupg3thjwhsabgevk6xmwhd2bbyxdc/container/../lib/pami_port/libcollectives.so.3(_ZN7LibColl18NativeInterfaceP2PILb1ELb0EE2>[a01n01:2969321] [15] /spack-envs/base/opt/linux-rhel8-ppc64le/gcc-9.1.0/spectrum-mpi-10.4.0.3-20210112-6jbupg3thjwhsabgevk6xmwhd2bbyxdc/container/../lib/pami_port/libpami.so.3(_ZN4PAMI8Protocol4Send11EagerSimpleINS_6Device3IB>[a01n01:2969321] [16] /spack-envs/base/opt/linux-rhel8-ppc64le/gcc-9.1.0/spectrum-mpi-10.4.0.3-20210112-6jbupg3thjwhsabgevk6xmwhd2bbyxdc/container/../lib/pami_port/libpami.so.3(PAMI_Context_advancev+0x994)[0x20000342a1b4]
[a01n01:2969321] [17] /spack-envs/base/opt/linux-rhel8-ppc64le/gcc-9.1.0/spectrum-mpi-10.4.0.3-20210112-6jbupg3thjwhsabgevk6xmwhd2bbyxdc/container/../lib/pami_port/libcollectives.so.3(LIBCOLL_Advance_pami+0x34)[0x200003abfb14]
[a01n01:2969321] [18] /spack-envs/base/opt/linux-rhel8-ppc64le/gcc-9.1.0/spectrum-mpi-10.4.0.3-20210112-6jbupg3thjwhsabgevk6xmwhd2bbyxdc/container/../lib/pami_port/libcollectives.so.3(LIBCOLL_Advance+0x18)[0x200003aaa128]
[a01n01:2969321] [19] /spack-envs/base/opt/linux-rhel8-ppc64le/gcc-9.1.0/spectrum-mpi-10.4.0.3-20210112-6jbupg3thjwhsabgevk6xmwhd2bbyxdc/container/../lib/spectrum_mpi/mca_coll_ibm.so(start_libcoll_blocking_collective+0x120)[0x>[a01n01:2969321] [20] /spack-envs/base/opt/linux-rhel8-ppc64le/gcc-9.1.0/spectrum-mpi-10.4.0.3-20210112-6jbupg3thjwhsabgevk6xmwhd2bbyxdc/container/../lib/spectrum_mpi/mca_coll_ibm.so(mca_coll_ibm_allgatherv+0x304)[0x2000039c11>[a01n01:2969321] [21] /spack-envs/base/opt/linux-rhel8-ppc64le/gcc-9.1.0/spectrum-mpi-10.4.0.3-20210112-6jbupg3thjwhsabgevk6xmwhd2bbyxdc/container/../lib/libmpi_ibm.so.3(PMPI_Allgatherv+0x154)[0x20000031cdd4]
[a01n01:2969321] [22] ./program_MPI[0x10004c84]
[a01n01:2969321] [23] /lib64/power9/libc.so.6(+0x24078)[0x200000544078]
[a01n01:2969321] [24] /lib64/power9/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xb4)[0x200000544264]
[a01n01:2969321] *** End of error message ***
```

GDB backtrace:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00002000035f1018 in ibv_madvise_range.part () from /lib64/libibverbs.so.1
#1  0x00002000035f29e0 in __ibv_common_reg_mr () from /lib64/libibverbs.so.1
#2  0x00002000035f2d0c in ibv_reg_mr () from /lib64/libibverbs.so.1
#3  0x00002000034584b8 in PAMI::Device::IBV::IBVMRManager::create_mr(void*, unsigned long, PAMI::Device::IBV::IBVMRElem*) ()
   from /spack-envs/base/opt/linux-rhel8-ppc64le/gcc-9.1.0/spectrum-mpi-10.4.0.3-20210112-6jbupg3thjwhsabgevk6xmwhd2bbyxdc/container/../lib/pami_port/libpami.so.3
#4  0x00002000034815bc in PAMI::MemregionCache::createMemregion(PAMI::Memregion*, unsigned long*, unsigned long, void*, unsigned long) ()
   from /spack-envs/base/opt/linux-rhel8-ppc64le/gcc-9.1.0/spectrum-mpi-10.4.0.3-20210112-6jbupg3thjwhsabgevk6xmwhd2bbyxdc/container/../lib/pami_port/libpami.so.3
#5  0x00002000034823cc in PAMI::Context::memregion_create_impl(void*, unsigned long, unsigned long*, unsigned long (*) [24]) ()
   from /spack-envs/base/opt/linux-rhel8-ppc64le/gcc-9.1.0/spectrum-mpi-10.4.0.3-20210112-6jbupg3thjwhsabgevk6xmwhd2bbyxdc/container/../lib/pami_port/libpami.so.3
#6  0x000020000342c1f8 in PAMI_Memregion_create () from /spack-envs/base/opt/linux-rhel8-ppc64le/gcc-9.1.0/spectrum-mpi-10.4.0.3-20210112-6jbupg3thjwhsabgevk6xmwhd2bbyxdc/container/../lib/pami_port/libpami.so.3
#7  0x00002000034deb1c in PAMI::Protocol::Send::EagerRget<PAMI::Device::IBV::PacketModel<PAMI::Device::IBV::Device, true>, PAMI::Device::IBV::DmaModel<PAMI::Device::IBV::Device, 1919ul> >::simple(pami_send_t*) ()
   from /spack-envs/base/opt/linux-rhel8-ppc64le/gcc-9.1.0/spectrum-mpi-10.4.0.3-20210112-6jbupg3thjwhsabgevk6xmwhd2bbyxdc/container/../lib/pami_port/libpami.so.3
#8  0x0000200003424a38 in PAMI_Send () from /spack-envs/base/opt/linux-rhel8-ppc64le/gcc-9.1.0/spectrum-mpi-10.4.0.3-20210112-6jbupg3thjwhsabgevk6xmwhd2bbyxdc/container/../lib/pami_port/libpami.so.3
#9  0x0000200003b9de7c in LibColl::NativeInterfaceP2P<true, false>::multicast_over_send (this=0x42e4cb80, send=0x44956450, length=<optimized out>) at ../../interfaces/default/Topology.h:323
#10 0x0000200003b9e3dc in LibColl::NativeInterfaceP2P<true, false>::multicast (this=0x42e4cb80, mcast=0x449562c8) at ../../adapter/pami/NativeInterface.h:560
#11 0x0000200003b48374 in CCMI::Executor::Allgatherv<CCMI::ConnectionManager::CommSeqConnMgr, libcoll_allgatherv_t>::sendNext (this=0x449560d0) at ../../math/math_util.h:16
#12 0x0000200003b48644 in CCMI::Executor::Allgatherv<CCMI::ConnectionManager::CommSeqConnMgr, libcoll_allgatherv_t>::notifyAvailRecvDone (context=<optimized out>, cookie=<optimized out>, result=<optimized out>)
    at ../../ccmi/executor/Allgatherv.h:525
#13 0x0000200003b8d43c in LibColl::NativeInterfaceP2P<true, false>::dispatch_mcast_short (context_hdl=<optimized out>, cookie=0x42e4cb80, header=<optimized out>, header_size=<optimized out>, data=0x20000e118030,
    data_size=<optimized out>, orig=<optimized out>, recv=<optimized out>) at ../../interfaces/default/PipeWorkQueue.h:209
#14 0x00002000034324ec in PAMI::Protocol::Send::EagerSimple<PAMI::Device::IBV::PacketModel<PAMI::Device::IBV::Device, true>, (PAMI::Protocol::Send::configuration_t)1>::dispatch_packed(void*, void*, unsigned long, void*, void*) ()
   from /spack-envs/base/opt/linux-rhel8-ppc64le/gcc-9.1.0/spectrum-mpi-10.4.0.3-20210112-6jbupg3thjwhsabgevk6xmwhd2bbyxdc/container/../lib/pami_port/libpami.so.3
#15 0x000020000342a1b4 in PAMI_Context_advancev () from /spack-envs/base/opt/linux-rhel8-ppc64le/gcc-9.1.0/spectrum-mpi-10.4.0.3-20210112-6jbupg3thjwhsabgevk6xmwhd2bbyxdc/container/../lib/pami_port/libpami.so.3
#16 0x0000200003abfb14 in LIBCOLL_Advance_pami (context=<optimized out>) at api.cc:87
#17 0x0000200003aaa128 in LIBCOLL_Advance (ctxt=<optimized out>) at libcoll.cc:137
#18 0x00002000039bfe50 in start_libcoll_blocking_collective ()
   from /spack-envs/base/opt/linux-rhel8-ppc64le/gcc-9.1.0/spectrum-mpi-10.4.0.3-20210112-6jbupg3thjwhsabgevk6xmwhd2bbyxdc/container/../lib/spectrum_mpi/mca_coll_ibm.so
#19 0x00002000039c11a4 in mca_coll_ibm_allgatherv () from /spack-envs/base/opt/linux-rhel8-ppc64le/gcc-9.1.0/spectrum-mpi-10.4.0.3-20210112-6jbupg3thjwhsabgevk6xmwhd2bbyxdc/container/../lib/spectrum_mpi/mca_coll_ibm.so
#20 0x000020000031cdd4 in PMPI_Allgatherv () from /spack-envs/base/opt/linux-rhel8-ppc64le/gcc-9.1.0/spectrum-mpi-10.4.0.3-20210112-6jbupg3thjwhsabgevk6xmwhd2bbyxdc/container/../lib/libmpi_ibm.so.3
#21 0x0000000010004c84 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffd1dd6f78) at program_MPI.c:765
(gdb)
```

line 765 of my code is the MPI_Allgatherv line.

Comment: Where does the segfault occur; have you tried using a debugger? Why do you think `MPI_Allgatherv` is the problem, and where is it even referenced?

Comment: Sorry, i edited the question so it includes the gdb backtrace

Comment: The result returned from `malloc()` et al does not need to be cast - `void *` has provided this magic in standard C for 35 years now.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your `double ****results_values_local;` variables. That is not a matrix, tensor, whatever you want to call it: it's a whole bunch of little arrays. MPI buffers have to be contiguous, that is they need to be of type `double*` or `int*`: pointer to a single array of some elementary type.

So you need to allocate your matrix as one big block. You can then create pointer arrays into it, or use an indexing macro:

```
#define INDEX(i,j,k) (k+n*(j+n*i))
```

so that you can write `result[ INDEX(i,j,k) ]`.

I will note that what you are doing is also really bad for scalar performance because it dances all over cache & TLB; it makes prefetching impossible, &c. Please unlearn this bad programming style.